# Number fields and algebraic integer

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Suppose there is a (algebraic) number field $K$.

Algebraic integer is a root of some monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

The elements of $K$ are the root of some monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

As the field is commutative, every monic equation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ can be converted into monic equation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ (By multiplying least common multiples of denominators in coefficients.) and have the same roots.

This suggests that every number in $K$ is an algebraic integer.

Is this right understanding? If not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: How do you convert $x+(2/3)=0$ to a monic equation with integer coefficients?

Comment: You can, indeed, convert any polynomial with rational coefficients to integer coefficients by clearing the denominators. It is the *monic* part that fails.

Comment: Note that *least* common multiples need not exist in arbitrary integral domains. But one can still clear denominators by multiplying by any nonzero common multiple, e.g. their product.

Comment: Any thoughts about the replies you have received, manin?